# How to add ingame tutorial for first time?

Tags: unity, c#

I want to know how to show tutorial when player playing for First time.
Only once

Comment: This would involve saving some information in your saved game or player prefs when you've shown your tutorial for the first time. When you want to show the tutorial, you check that saved data - if you already wrote the "I've finished showing the tutorial" message there, then you can skip displaying it this time. How have you tried implementing this so far, and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) to store persistent data on the user's device.

In order to decide whether or not to play the tutorial, find out if the player already completed the tutorial with

```
if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Tutorial_Completed") == 1) {
```

After the player completed the tutorial, set the variable with:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Tutorial_Completed", 1);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

Comment: made  a ui just it is like image it should come when user is playing for first time how should i give the setint getint values

Comment: @MustafaAhmed If your tutorial is all in one GameObject, then I would recommend to put that in the Start method and use `SetActive(false);` to deactivate it immediately on a second playthrough. But that really depends on how exactly you implemented your tutorial. There is never just one way to do something in Unity. If you want more specific answers, you need to provide more information in your question.